# How can I take mulltiple inputs using a for loop in file handling?

Tags: c++

When the loop is completed, only the last data entry is written in the file; how can I solve this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char name[50];
    char reg[10];
    char address[100];
    char nationality[50];
    char cnumber[50];
    char marks[50]; 
    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter the following data"<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"enter your name\n";
        cin.getline(name,50);
        cout<<"enter your reg no.\n";
        cin.getline(reg,10);
        cout<<"enter your address\n";
        cin.getline(address,100);
        cout<<"enter your nationality\n";
        cin.getline(nationality,50);
        cout<<"enter your number\n";
        cin.getline(cnumber,50);
        cout<<"enter your marks\n";
        cin.getline(marks,50);
        cout<<endl;
        //--------------------------------//////////////////////////////////////////////--------------------------
        ofstream x("LOTR.txt");
        x<<name<<endl;
        x<<reg<<endl;
        x<<address<<endl;
        x<<nationality<<endl;
        x<<cnumber<<endl;
        x<<marks<<endl;
        x.close();
        char name2[50];
        char reg2[10];
        char address2[100];
        char nationality2[50];
        char cnumber2[50];
        char marks2[50];
        ifstream y("LOTR.txt");
        y.getline(name2,50);
        y.getline(reg2,50);
        y.getline(address2,100);
        y.getline(nationality2,50);
        y.getline(cnumber2,50);
        y.getline(marks2,50);
        cout<<"name is: "<<name2<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"registration number is: "<<reg2<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Address is: "<<address2<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Nationality is: "<<nationality2<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Contact number is: "<<cnumber2<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Marks are: "<<marks2<<endl;      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to be output?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening and closing the `LOTR.txt` file twice per loop iteration, once for output and then for input. Each time you open the file for output, you are **overwriting** the existing file. That is why only the last data entry is present in the file when the loop is finished.

Either move the file open/close logic outside of the loop, or else enable the [`app` or `ate` flag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) when opening the output file to preserve its existing content.